# Recuperar valor da view para controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, view, controller

Objetivo: Recuperar valor da view para a controller [HttpPost]

Criei uma classe generica com gets e sets

```
public int ListarDadosCarteira_Resultado { get; set; }
public string ListarDadosCarteira_Descricao { get; set; }    
public int ListarDadosCarteira_Total { get; set; }
```

Atualizando!! 
Carregando View Completa uso duas model está apenas uma pois tirei a segunda para teste.

```
    @model Tuple<Generic>
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";}
    <div class="painel">
    <div class="painel-header">
        <div class="painel-header-text-search">Carteira Mapa</div>
    </div>

    <div class="painel-content">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {  
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Index</legend>


                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Item1.ListarDadosCarteira_Total , new { @class = "newText" })            
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Item1.ListarDadosCarteira_Descricao , new { @class = "newText" })  
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Item1.ListarDadosCarteira_Resultado , new { @class = "newText" })  

                <div class="field-row">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <div class="posicao-botao">
                                <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" class="button-search" title="Pesquisar Funcionario Fixa" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </fieldset>            
        }
    </div>
</div>
     @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Agora vem minha duvida como recupero o valor inserido quando eu realizar um [HttpPost] ?

Pois costumo trazer assim.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Generic generica)
    {
    }
```

Mas seu eu fizer dessa forma não está me trazendo valores.

Comment: Poste sua View completa aqui

Comment: @Randrade Obrigado pela primeira resposta, acabei de atualizei conforme solicitado.

Comment: Você não precisa usar o `Tuple`. Você usa o mesmo quando precisa passar mais de um `Model` para a view, o que não é o seu caso. O nome da sua View é `Index` também, correto? Somente com o `Model`, sem o `Tuple` não funcionou?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ideia é essa mesma que você postou, criar seu model para receber em sua Action:

```
public class Generic
{
    public int ListarDadosCarteira_Resultado { get; set; }
    public string ListarDadosCarteira_Descricao { get; set; }
    public int ListarDadosCarteira_Total { get; set; }
}
```

Depois criar seu controller com sua action:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MetodoParaReceberSeuPost(Generic generica)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

E depois sua view, lembrando de tipar usando o `@model`

```
@model Mvc4WebBootstrap1.Models.Generic

@using (Html.BeginForm("suaAction", "seuController"))
{ 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ListarDadosCarteira_Descricao)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ListarDadosCarteira_Resultado)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ListarDadosCarteira_Total)

    <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
}
```

No mais é isso :)

Comment: Obrigado pela primeira resposta.
Estou fazendo exatamente isso mas tem o retorno sem valor.
adicionei um complemento da minha pergunta talvez ajude a tentar localizar o problema.

Comment: @EdgarAraujo Basta fazer igual a resposta do Brunno. Você está passando `@model Tuple<Generic>`. Passe o model igual a resposta que deve resolver seu problema.

Comment: @Randrade Pior que estou fazendo igual e não tem retorno.
Acho que e algo relacionado ao Tuple, pois e a primeira vez que uso.
tem mais alguma sugestão ?

Comment: @EdgarAraujo, esse `Tuple<Generic>` está estranho mesmo, tente passar direto igual no meu exemplo e lembre de setar a action e o controller no `@using (Html.BeginForm("suaAction", "seuController"))`, qualquer estou a disposição :)